# Cannot run Google Standard App Engine through Maven

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, web-applications, gcloud

I have to make a web application running on google App Engine and using maven to manage it (run local server, deploy the live version etc.). I followed the guide here and after making the project using

`mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.59 -Djava8=true -DCloudSDK_Tooling=true -Dapplication-id=progrweb2021 -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:`

i'm not able to run it with `mvn appengine:run`, not even with an IDE such as Netbeans or IntelliJ (where i added the google code plugin in both cases). If i run the command with the `-e` parameters (full stack trace) it gives me

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.156 s <<< FAILURE! - in it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest
[ERROR] doGet_writesResponse(it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest)  Time elapsed: 0.044 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.setUp(HelloAppEngineTest.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @10bbd20a
        at it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.setUp(HelloAppEngineTest.java:39)

[ERROR] doGet_writesResponse(it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest)  Time elapsed: 0.045 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalEnvironment.callRequestEndListeners()" because the return value of "com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()" is null
        at it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.tearDown(HelloAppEngineTest.java:53)

[ERROR] HelloInfo_test(it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer$3
        at it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.setUp(HelloAppEngineTest.java:39)

[ERROR] HelloInfo_test(it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalEnvironment.callRequestEndListeners()" because the return value of "com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()" is null
        at it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.tearDown(HelloAppEngineTest.java:53)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR] it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.HelloInfo_test(it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest)
[ERROR]   Run 1: HelloAppEngineTest.setUp:39 » NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class org.m...
[ERROR]   Run 2: HelloAppEngineTest.tearDown:53 » NullPointer Cannot invoke "com.google.appengi...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest.doGet_writesResponse(it.units.progrweb2021.HelloAppEngineTest)
[ERROR]   Run 1: HelloAppEngineTest.setUp:39 » ExceptionInInitializer
[ERROR]   Run 2: HelloAppEngineTest.tearDown:53 » NullPointer Cannot invoke "com.google.appengi...
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.517 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-21T14:04:18+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project ProgrWebProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/myPC/Documents/University/WebDev/Progetto/ProgrWebProject/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project ProgrWebProject: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/myPC/Documents/University/WebDev/Progetto/ProgrWebProject/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/myPc/Documents/University/WebDev/Progetto/ProgrWebProject/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException (SurefireHelper.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:937)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Additional info: i'm on Manjaro, and `mvn -v` gives me

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (NON-CANONICAL_2021-04-26T21:52:54Z_root)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 16.0.1, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.49-1-manjaro", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I know that the steps are legits because i followed the same as my professor, but still is not working. Do you have any idea why? Maybe something wrong with the jdk? the pom.xml is generated by default.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have at least one problem with the error `There are test failures.`. Often when you use Maven to generate a project template, it includes a stub test directory/file too. I suspect (!?) this test source|class is either incorrect or unused. I'd start by reviewing it. You may be able to simply delete it and try again.